# Is it possible in PHP to replace parent with children in a class property?

Tags: php, oop

If a polymorphism applies, it should be possible to replace the parents with a child anywhere, because the child contains all the necessary properties. It always meets the parent class interface. In addition, it can expand it.

Here is a very simplified example:

```
class A {
    public int $x;
}

class B extends A {
    public int $y;
}

class C {
    public A $ca;
}

class D extends C {
    public B $ca;
}

$vd = new D();
$vd->cd->x = 10;

echo $vd->cd->x;
```

> Error: Type of D::$ca must be A (as in class C)

Classes `A` and `C` are in the library and classes `B` and `D` override them.

Comment: I never had such a problem, but reading the error message its probably not possible. You could make the attribute private and grant access only via getter and setter methods. That way you can force when setting the attribute whether it meets your criteria. Whatever you're trying to do, there must be a better way. Maybe we could help you if you could elaborate why you need this.

Comment: Side note: you call `$vd->cd` in your example, but `$cd` is not defined in any of the classes. Did you mean to use `ca` instead of `cd`?

Comment: In practice, classes A and C are part of the library. Class A is factory and class B is singleton. I need to replace (extend) class B with class D. This can be achieved by overloading the get method of class A with class C. The entire application (both library and application) then uses class D instead of B. This works well, but in classes A and C, the type must not be specified for a property containing an instance of class C (D). Then it writes the mistake mentioned above.

Comment: If this property is private, the library code will use an instance of class B and the application an instance of class D. Therefore, it is not a singleton!

Answer (score 0):

Typed properties are **invariant** in PHP.

From [the original RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2#inheritance_and_variance) for typed properties:

> Property types are invariant. This means that the type of a (non-private) property is not allowed to change during inheritance (this includes adding or removing property types). If the parent property is private, then the type may be changed arbitrarily.

> The reason why property types are invariant is that they can be both read from and written to. The change from int to ?int implies that reads from the property may now also return null in addition to integers. The change from ?int to int implies that it is no longer possible to write null to the property. As such, neither contravariance nor covariance are applicable to property types.

What you *can* do safely, is use an *instance* of `B` wherever an *instance* of `A` was expected:

```php
class C {
    public A $ca;
}

$c = new C();
$c->ca = new B();
```

... thus fulfilling [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), that *"if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S"*